# IntelliJ doesn't see confugured log4J .xml file

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, log4j, intellij-14

I want to show only error logs in the console and I indicated that in .xml file, also want to have timestamps but as you can see, the information is not visible in the console. I get positive logs as well, which is not correct.
Most of the tips are for Eclipse project and how to build the path.
Could anyone help me with this issue?

Thank you in advance.
[updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNJKj.png)

[image: log4j]

Comment: If you are using maven the java source should me inside `src\main\java` and classpath resources should be inside `src\main\resources` folder also place the `log4j.xml` should be in root of the `sec\main\resources` folder

Comment: I've updated the source paths as in the attached ("updated") file and still it does not work ;/

Comment: Move the log4j.xml to `src\main\resources` from `src\main\resources\Resources`

Comment: IDE console does not use your log4j configuration. Console tab shows only your application standard/error output. Only if your application produces log files you can configure them in [Logs tab of IDE Run/Debug Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-application.html#logsTab).

Comment: To filter log entries in console tab try this plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console

Answer (score 0):

1. place the log xml file in the path src\main\resources
2. Name of the xml file should be "Log4j2.xml"

It should work.